# Hibernate transaction rollback required or is close sufficient?

Tags: hibernate

Considering the following (simplified) scenario in Hibernate:

```
Session session=sessionFactory.openSession();
Transaction tx=session.beginTransaction();
try {
    //Do something with session
    if (...) {
        return something;
    }
    tx.commit();
}
finally {
    session.close();
}
```

Is it a safe practice to return without explicitly rolling back, i.e. will the session.close() statement without an explicit rollback being called in the code fragment result in an eventual rollback?

Answer (score 1):

Not knowing how complex your real code may be, nevertheless, it is not best practice to not rollback in catch/finally. Here's how my current code looks like :

```
try{ .....

transaction = session.beginTransaction();  .....
// Finally commit the changes...
        transaction.commit();
}catch (Exception ex) {
        LOG.error(blah);
        transaction.rollback();
        throw new STDException("An error occured ",
                ex);
    } finally {
        session.close();
    }
```